# Linking View Controller to Storyboard objective c

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I know that this should be very easy but I haven't been able to find out how to do it. The suggestions that I have do not work. I basically have a view controller in my storyboard and I want to link it to a MyController.m file which I created manually.

I was wondering what the proper way of doing that is. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Click on the viewController which you want to associate with that
   specific class.

   [image: Step 1]
2. Go to the utilities pane (right-most column, where properties etc
   are found).
3. On the identity inspector (3rd tab from left), you will see a
   section called custom class.
4. Fill in the name of your class there.

   [image: Steps 2, 3 and 4]